# Dead Code Stripping causing Compile errors

Tags: ios, swift, vuforia, widevine

We were using widevine DRM player in our project. While integrating we had to make "Dead Code Stripping" to NO. It was working fine.

Now we had to add other classes and .a files(Unity Vuforia files) in the project. For it we had to revert "Dead Code Stripping" to YES. In debug mode everything works fine and widevine DRM Player works fine. But in archive builds it crashed immediately. If "Dead Code Stripping" is set to No then we are getting following errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture
>   arm64:"Geo::GetiOSAppDocumentsDir()", referenced
>   from:Geo::PathUtils::GetSandboxDataPath() in
>   libiPhone-lib.a(GeoPathUtils.o)

For widevine player to work we need "Dead Code Stripping" to NO and for unity files we need it to be "YES". How can we resolve the issue? Any advice is welcomed.